# Magento 2 Composer error - The contents from the "/vendor/magento/module-media-gallery-synchronization-api/etc/module.xml" file can't be read

Tags: magento2, composer

We upgraded to Magento 2.4 and exec recompile

All is OK no warning

Only when I open the frontend I see the error below `Magento 2 Composer error - The contents from the "/vendor/magento/module-media-gallery-synchronization-api/etc/module.xml" file can't be read`

Did we forget something? is some package missing? I was looking for `module-media-gallery-synchronization-api` in composer but cannot find it

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): The contents from the "/vendor/magento/module-media-gallery-synchronization-api/etc/module.xml" file can't be read. Warning!file_get_contents(/vendor/magento/module-media-gallery-synchronization-api/etc/module.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): The contents from the "/home/sohbv/public_html/m2_dev/vendor/magento/module-media-gallery-synchronization-api/etc/module.xml" file can't be read. Warning!file_get_contents(/home/sohbv/public_html/m2_dev/vendor/magento/module-media-gallery-synchronization-api/etc/module.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList\Loader->getModuleConfigs() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/ModuleList/Loader.php:83]
#2 Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList\Loader->load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/ModuleList.php:72]
#3 Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList->getAll() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/ModuleList.php:91]
#4 Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList->getOne() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php:144]
#5 Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isModuleVersionEqual() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php:59]
#6 Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isSchemaUpToDate() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php:103]
#7 Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->getDbVersionErrors() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php:119]
#8 Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->getGroupedDbVersionErrors() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php:53]
#9 Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->beforeDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:121]
#10 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/mirasvit/module-cache-warmer/src/CacheWarmer/Plugin/Debug/OnHitPlugin.php:147]
#11 Mirasvit\CacheWarmer\Plugin\Debug\OnHitPlugin->aroundAroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#12 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#13 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin/Interceptor.php:26]
#14 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:40]
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have module **Magento_MediaGallerySynchronizationApi** installed

This module is part of Magento 2.4. After that clear cache, and if you are in developer mode delete everything from generated/* directory and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the module is indeed installed and present in the `vendor` folder and also in `composer.lock`. If its there, delete the vendor folder, run `composer install` and after that check for permissions on the vendor folder.

Comment: I added it to "require" somehow it was lost or maybe it is a "replace" statements elsewhere?

Comment: if its not present in either `composer.lock` or in your `vendor` folder , then simply re-require it with `magento/module-media-gallery-synchronization-api `